# Freeform and responsive layout

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have created two columns form using Freeform composer, but it looks like each field is counted as a new row. At that case responsive layout is "breaking" form flow on mobile devices.

Is there any way to do have predefined columns first then rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that composer has issue withing new FireFox. Have used Chrome and drag-n-drop can drag without creating new rows per each field.

Comment: Ah, than that's a bug you can report at Solspace: http://support.solspace.com/support/tickets/new

Comment: Is there any way to add own classes to each column or form field?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use the composer. I always use the free version of Freeform so I have complete control over my HTML. The only downside is that you can't reorder or create form fields that change automatically in your front-end templates.